# duplicated results in dynamically created divs in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

When users in my comment section answer a comment I need the "show number of answer" to be updated using ajax...

And my script does exactly that - except because the answer section is dynamically created in a loop it creates a instance for all answer sections...

**Ex. 3 comment with 9, 27, 23 answers respectively**

> What I want:

user submits an answer to comment 2
It now shows the updated number of answers (ie. 28) under comment 2

> What I get:

user submits an answer to comment 2
It now shows the updated number of answers for every single comment (ie. 9, 28, 23 respectively) under comment 2

```
// comment 1
9 answers

// comment 2
9 answers
28 answers
23 answers
// after whole page refresh it goes back to just
28 answers

// comment 3
23 answers
```

> How do I fix either my setup or my jQuery loads to get what I want?

My basic setup:
v.php (page with comments)

```
<div id="commentAll">
    // loop to write all comment
        <div id="answerAll">
            // answer textarea + button
            // loop to write all answers to this comment
                <div id="answerCount">
                <div id="answerShow">

// So it ends up looking like this

<div id="commentAll">
    // comment 1
        <div id="answerAll">
            // answer textarea + button
            <div id="answerCount">
                9 answers
            <div id="answerShow">
                // answer 1
                // answer 2
                .
                .
    // comment 2
        <div id="answerAll">
            // answer textarea + button
            <div id="answerCount">
                // before user has posted an answer
                27 answers
                // and after user has posted an answer
                9 answers
                28 answers
                23 answers
            <div id="answerShow">
                // answer 1
                // answer 2
                .
                .
    // comment 3
        <div id="answerAll">
            // answer textarea + button
            <div id="answerCount">
                23 answers
            <div id="answerShow">
                // answer 1
                // answer 2
                .
                .
```

jQuery.js

```
var self = $(this);
// Update database
success:function(){
    var countAnswer = self.closest('#answerAll').find('[id^="answerCount"]');
    var showAnswer = self.closest('#answerAll').find('[id^="answerShow"]');
    countAnswer.load(location.href + " #answerCount>*", "");
    showAnswer.load(location.href + " #answerShow>*", "");
    closestDiv.find('textarea').val('') ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ID parameter in HTML should be unique. You should set up your html to use unique id's like `<div id="answerCount3"></div>` for comment 3 , this way you will be able to access the particular element to update it's content. For example -  If your API call returns the count of answers like this -

`[1: "9 answers",2: "28 answers", 3: "23 answers"]`

you can use following jQuery code to update your html:

```
// given that result contains [1: "9 answers",2: "28 answers", 3: "23 answers"] 
$.each(result, function( key, value ) {
    $("#answerCount"+key).html(value);  
}
```